# Lerna commands keep hanging

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, monorepo, lerna

I try to run different Lerna commands, but then the console freezes at

`lerna notice cli v8.0.1`

It doesn't show any error message, it just freezes. I tried to run the command with `--loglevel verbose` This shows me the following message:

```
lerna notice cli v8.0.1
lerna verb packageConfigs Explicit "packages" configuration found in lerna.json. Resolving packages using the configured glob(s): ["packages/ui","packages/core"]
lerna verb rootPath /Users/user/Documents/Projects/Project-1
```

My co-workers use the same repo and they succeed in using lerna commands, so it is a local issue.

Node version: 21.5.0
NPM version: 10.2.5
MacOS: 14.2.1

I tried using different lerna versions, npm versions and node versions. I also tried reinstalling my mac os.

Comment: I would suggest you use the `silly` log level which will tell you exactly which command it failed with. Also just an idea but could it be that your coworkers are on Windows OS? I'm asking because that OS is case insensitive vs Mac that is case sensitive